# How to manipulate the following XML string using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, xml.etree

I am trying to manipulate the XML using xml.etree API. I am modifying specific elements inside a tag something like this

```
get = root.findall(.//TASK/*[@FROM='mmb/image1.0'])
for i in get:
    i.append(ET.fromstring('<INSTALL_OPTIONS updateType="new"/>'))

get2 = root.findall(.//TASK/*[@FROM='mmb/image2.2'])
for j in get2:
    j.append(ET.fromstring('<INSTALL_OPTIONS updateType="new"/>'))
```

Now, instead of running a separate loop each time for each element of the `FROM` tag, I need to store all the attributes in a single list and just use the loop once something like this

```
from = ['mmb/image1.0','mmb/image2.2']
for loop_parse in from:
    get_file = root.findall(.//TASK/*[@FROM='loop_parse'])
    for j in get_file:
        j.append(ET.fromstring('<INSTALL_OPTIONS updateType="new"/>'))
```

Firstly can this be achieved? Secondly I'm not sure about this syntax `get_file = root.findall(.//TASK/*[@FROM='loop_parse'])`

For **reference** the XML is something like this

```
<TASK>
 <FILE FROM='mmb/image1.0'/>
  <A>..</A>
  <B>..</B>
  <INSTALL_OPTIONS updateType="new"/>
 </FILE>
 <FILE FROM='mmb/image2.0'/>
  <C>..</C>
  <D>..</D>
  <INSTALL_OPTIONS updateType="new"/>
 </FILE>
</TASK>
```

Comment: Is the xml file in your question the current file or your expected output?

Comment: The expected output.

Comment: It should be crystal clear what the input is and what the expected output is. It is not enough to just show us the output. Both input and output must be well-formed.